# PHP: Set second dropdown options based on first dropdown choosen option using kartik Select2

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2, kartik-v

I've an application using yii2 framework.
I'm trying to use select option (dropdown select), and I use **Kartik Select2**.

This is the view of my select option
[image]

In pics above you can see I've two select option, but I've condition. This is the condition.

My first dropdown option(**transaction id**) contain 2 options, there are

1. Buy
2. Sell

and if user choose the `1. Buy`, the second dropdown option(**payment method**) will show

1. Cash
2. E-money transaction
   as options, and will show `1. Cash` only as option if user choose `2. Sell`.

**How do I can do it using Kartik Select2?**

Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Gonna need the relevant code you already have.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you need to update the second dropdown options based on first dropdown. First assign ids for dropdowns, first one id will be first-dropdown and second one id will be second-dropdown. add below code inside in your first dropdown change event.

```
// get first dropdown value here
var firstDropdownValue = $("#first-dropdown").select2("val");


var $secondDropdown = $('#second-dropdown');

// get all second dropdown options
var options = $secondDropdown.data('select2').options.options;

// delete all options of the native select element
$secondDropdown.html('');

// build new items
var items = [];

items.push({
    "id": 1,  // value of option
    "text": 'Cash' // name of option
});

$secondDropdown.append("<option value=\"1\">Cash</option>");

// check the first dropdown value and add E-money option
if(firstDropdownValue == 1){
    items.push({
        "id": 2,
        "text": 'E-money'
    });

    $secondDropdown.append("<option value=\"2\">E-money</option>");
}

// add new items
options.data = items;
$secondDropdown.select2(options);
```